# Page doesn't postback after clicking OK in confirm box for Radiobuttonlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a RadioButtonList with 2 items. I want a postback when any of the items is selected. I have added a confirm box for one item of RadioButtonList. But, when I click OK in the confirmbox, there is no postback and SelectedIndexChanged event is not getting fired.

AutoPostback property of RadioButtonList is set to true.
This is a code fragment from my Page_Load method:

```
RadioButtonOpenRestricted.Attributes.Add("AutoPostBack", "True");
RadioButtonOpenRestricted.Items.FindByValue("Open Access").Attributes.Add("AutoPostBack", "True");
RadioButtonOpenRestricted.Items.FindByValue("Open Access").Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:return confirm('Are you sure?');");
```

Earlier, I had added confirm box for entire RadioButtonList and postback was working as expected. But I want the confirm box to be displayed only when user clicks on "Open Access" item.

Please help!

---

I tried a few things. The new code lines look like:

RadioButtonOpenRestricted.Items.FindByValue("Open Access").Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:showConfirmBox(0,'" + RadioButtonOpenRestricted.ClientID + "')");
        RadioButtonOpenRestricted.Items.FindByValue("Restricted Access").Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:showConfirmBox(1,'" + RadioButtonOpenRestricted.ClientID + "')");

The javascript method is:

function showConfirmBox(i,id) 
    {
        if(i==0)
        {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to provide Open Access? All existing individual permissions will be removed!")==true)
            {
                var ctrl1 = document.getElementById(id + "_0");
                ctrl1.selected=true;
            }
            else
            {
                var ctrl2 = document.getElementById(id + "_1");
                 ctrl2.selected=true;
            }
        }
        if(i==1)
        {
            var ctrl2 = document.getElementById(id + "_1");
            ctrl2.selected=true;
        }
    }

The problem with this code is that it is treating both OK and Cancel as same. The confirm box is getting displayed but if-else part of the javascript method is not getting called. I tried using OnClientClick also...this doesnt even display the Confirmbox.

Help!!!

Comment: If you are using C# add another tag C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your on click script does not play well with auto-post back script generated by the ASP.NET. A quick hack solution can be

```
RadioButtonOpenRestricted.AutoPostBack = true;
RadioButtonOpenRestricted.Items.FindByValue("Open Access").Attributes.Add("OnClick", "if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) return false;");
```

Although, this will still give you an issue when you cancel on your confirmation box (in such case, you have to add script to select the previous radio button again).

As such I am not a great fan of radio button list - you may consider alternate mechanism such as repeater with radio button in item template and having your own java-script for confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `OnClientClick` to show a "confirm" window.

I don't think you can have a javascript confirm window perform a postback, at least not the way your code is set up.

You should set the OnClientClick to show a confirm modal or window with an `<asp:Button/>` and have that button perform the postback your looking for.

Comment: I had the following line in my code:
RadioButtonOpenRestricted.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:return confirm('Are you sure you want to provide Open Access to this document? All existing permissions will be removed!');");

and the postback was happening. It just that when I changed this to add to a particular item of RadioButtonList, postback stopped working.

Comment: The above posted solution is correct.  If you are setting the attributes on the server side, i believe you required OnClientClick

Comment: I tried changing "OnClick" to "OnClientClick". Now the confirm box is not displaying at all.

If I simply add the line below, postback happens but with double click on the OK button of the confirm box:
RadioButtonOpenRestricted.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:return confirm('Are you sure');");

Answer (score 0):

Khushboo, it used to happen with me many times. The reason behind that was I was missing some closing tag somewhere in my aspx page. I used to copy my whole aspx page to some other text editor and paste all the elements one by one to my aspx page. It always solved my this problem. I am sure you must be missing some closing tag, please cross check all elements.